# Typescript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2022

I have an existing application developed using the following:

- Visual Studio 2022
- Typescript 4.9
- ASP.NET
- JQuery

The Typescript code does not have module in it, and I am trying to add module.

**Example Existing Code:**

*EmployeeSearch.Control.ts*

```
class EmployeeSearchControl {
static Name = 'Test Name';
}
```

*EmployeeSearch.Component.ts*

```
class EmployeeSearchComponent extends EmployeeSearchControl {

  public static GetName() {
     //code
  }
}
```

I tried to add module to the existing code as shown below,

**Example Modified Code:**

*EmployeeSearch.Control.ts*

```
export class EmployeeSearchControl {
static Name = 'Test Name';
}
```

*EmployeeSearch.Component.ts*

```
import { EmployeeSearchControl } from "./EmployeeSearch.Controls";
export class EmployeeSearchComponent extends EmployeeSearchControl {

  public static GetName() {
     //code
  }
}
```

The code is compiling but, when I run it I am getting error,

> Typescript - Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'

Other details are given below,

*Bundle Config:*

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/Scripts/Employee")                 
             .IncludeDirectory("~/App/Modules/Employee/", "*.js")
        );
```

*.aspx page:*

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <%: Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Employee") %>
</asp:Content>
```

*TS Config:*

```
  {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Please advise what am I missing? How I can add module to existing Typescript code? I do not have nodejs dependency in my project. Any suggestion/direction will be greatly appreciated.